# I can't switch to another activity by clicking on the button? I have to simulate a multiactivity

Tags: android

I am reproducing a multiactivity situation where I have multiple java classes with the same code and equal xml classes with a button inside that should make me switch from one activity to another. When I run the code it gives me this type of error. Can you tell me why?

```
package com.example.multiactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
    }

    public void lanciaActivity(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
        //Settando il seguente flag l'activity che viene lanciata non verrà salvata nel backstack!
        //i.setFlags(i.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This is the error message when I run the app.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.multiactivity, PID: 21264
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6088)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27773)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6083)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299) 
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27773) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445) 
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.multiactivity/com.example.multiactivity.Activity1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2016)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4688)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4646)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5007)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4975)
        at com.example.multiactivity.MainActivity.lanciaActivity(MainActivity.java:19)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6083) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299) 
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27773) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21264 SIG: 9
Process 21264 terminated.
```

`Activity2` is equal to `Activity1`, except that `Activity2` launches `Activity3` instead.

The xml of the button is as follows:

```
 <Button 
  android:id="@+id/button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/textView" 
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:onClick="lanciaActivity" 
  android:text="Passa a altra Activity" />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the code of the Activity2 class?

Comment: look xml:

 <Button
        android:onClick="lanciaActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button!" />

Comment: @vatbub it is the same as this; only the activity reference class changes, that is activity3.class

Comment: @Muzafferus this is my xml code of main 
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="lanciaActivity"
        android:text="Passa a altra Activity" />

Comment: "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?" - this being Activity1

Comment: XD I forgot to include the activities in the manifest. Now that I have entered them everything works. Thanks for reminding me. @Nikos Hidalgo

Comment: Hey, nice to hear that it works. For the future, if you want to add more details to your question, please _do not_ post the details in the comments, rather edit your question instead. This makes the question look nice and tidy. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you initiated the intent improperly try added the current activity name instead of getapplicationcontext();

Answer (score 0):

If you looked at the second "Caused by" in your error message, it asks at the end "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?" This is the problem. You have to add the activity to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

`<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"/>`

You can also add whatever properties you need under the android:label. That worked for me.